# NPM module but it is depended on module dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, rollup

I have made NPM angular module (directive)  but when it is install,it is only working on particular angular version on which that module is made.

if npm module is made on `angular v5` then it will only works on `angular v5` not on `angular v2` or `angular v4`.

My question is how can make that module dependencies(like `@angular/core`, `@angular/forms`) depend on that modules which uses has currently in that repositry. or their are any settings which can perform this on `Rollup/tsconfig` file.

Or i have to make multiple modules for multiple version ?

what i am using is --

- ROLLUP as bundler
- tsconfig for TS

Comment: Which dependencies you use directly? Because in different version of angular modules are changed.

Comment: @Verri i have mentioned in question  - @angular/core, @angular/forms

Comment: I mean modules, like `FormsModule`. If you using forms maybe you need to import `ReactiveFormsModule`, `FormsModule` and `CommonModule`